# #1064 MySql error in nested query statements

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Here is the nested query i am using:

```
insert into ( select dbtable from profiles where ( email = 'blah@test.com' ) ) values ( null, null, 'blah@test.com', 'testing' )
```

the tablename will be fetched by the SELECT query for the INSERT query to run but i am getting this #1064 error.

I get another error of "#1103 - Incorrect table name" if i use back-ticks like this:

```
insert into `( select dbtable from profiles where ( email = 'blah@test.com' ) )` values ( null, null, 'blah@test.com', 'testing' )
```

I tried and searched for this but still i am stuck here. Can anybody help?

Sorry if this is an easy question as i am a newbie in this.

Comment: Maybe you want update?For insert the syntax is `INSERT INTO tableName  VALUES(1,2,3)` assuming the table has 3 columns.

Comment: I know the insert query and as mentioned, i want the tablename to come from the SELECT query that i nested inside the INSERT query..

Comment: If you put in your question some details about your tables and what are you trying to do,people might help.Right now its not clear at all what you want.

Comment: You can do that with dynamic sql in a stored procedure, see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html

Comment: profiles is a table which has a column named "dbtable". I want to fetch that value corresponding to particular email in the table profiles. @Mihai

Comment: can i use it with php? If yes, can you give an example so that it gets more clear? @VMai

Comment: SELECT  dbtable FROM profiles WHERE email = 'blah@test.com'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select dbtable from profiles where ( email = 'blah@test.com' ) into @tableName;
set @queryy = CONCAT(CONCAT('INSERT INTO ', @tableName), ' values ( null, null, \'blah@test.com\', \'testing\' )');

prepare myQuery from @queryy;
execute myQuery;
deallocate prepare myQuery;
```

I think it should help you solve your problem.

Comment: Hey @Luis

Tried that but there is an error on "prepare myQuery FROM @queryy"

ERROR: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax

Comment: I don't have your DB to test but try run "SELECT @queryy" before the "prepare" and post the output here.

Comment: Thank you so much @Luis

Its working as is. Without "SELECT @queryy" before the "prepare"

Thanks again